# php - search an array for a string

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php // SEARCH TAGS FOR A SPECIFIC TAG
  $tags = CollectionAttributeKey::getByHandle('recipe_tags'); // attribute handle of tags to search
  $tagToFind = 'Videos'; // declare the specific tag to find
  $selectedTags = array($page->getAttribute($tags->getAttributeKeyHandle())); // get tags associated with each page and put them in an array

  foreach ($selectedTags as $tag) { // output tags separately

    echo $tag; // ECHO TEST - check that individual tags associated with each page are outputting correctly

    if ($tag == $tagToFind) { // if $tag is equal to $tagToFind
      echo ' Found';
    } else {
      echo ' Not found';
      }
  }
?>
```

`echo $tag;` outputs the list of tags associated with each page so I'm pretty sure the issue is how I'm checking if 'Videos' is in the list of tags.

The above outputs the following list: `Breakfast` `Brunch` `Budget` `Meal` `Easy` `Lunch` `Quick Meals` `Supper` `Vegetarian` `Videos` and `Not found` even though Videos is in the list.

I've also tried using in_array to look for 'Videos' like this:

```
if (in_array($tagToFind, $selectedTags, true)) { // search the array for $tagToFind - true = strict
  echo ' Found';
} else { 
    echo ' Not found';
  }
```

But get the same result - I'm new to php so sorry if this is easy.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$page->getAttribute($tags->getAttributeKeyHandle())
```

seems to return a string.

In that case

```
$selectedTags = array($page->getAttribute($tags->getAttributeKeyHandle()));
```

makes no sense - you get an array containing one long string.

What you want to to is:

$selectedTags = $page->getAttribute($tags->getAttributeKeyHandle());

```
if(stristr($selectedTags, $tagToFind)){
  // do something
}
else{
  // do something else
}
```

Comment: Awesome - easy when you know how!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that $selectedTags an array of one string, since your `foreach` only loops once

You should try doing

```
$selectedTags = explode(" ",$page->getAttribute($tags->getAttributeKeyHandle()));
```

Then use `in_array` function

Answer (score 0):

Then Better to use....

```
if(strcmp($tag , $tagToFind))
{
    echo "Found";
}
else
{
    echo "Not found";
}
```

may this works for you